# Laravel 4: Multiple Action in a Single Contnroller Not Working?

Tags: laravel-4, controller

I am new to Laravel and am just stuck upon this thing. I have set a controller which contains multiple actions for application. It turns out that if I put a single action in a single controller class, it works quite well. But when I use multiple action. It gives that damn error "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."
So, exactly what am I doing wrong? below is my controller class:

```
<? php
class ProgController extends BaseController
{
public function showHome()
{
return View::make('home');
}
public function showLogin()
{
return ('you are not authorized to login yet');
}
public function showTravel()
{
return View::make('travel');
}
}
```

and here is the route.php file content:

```
Route::get('/', 'ProgController@showHome');
Route::get('/login', 'ProgController@showLogin');
Route::get('/travel', 'ProgController@showTravel');
```

the files are in their respective default folders. I am worried has it something to do with composer.json file or what? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on debugging in your app/config/app.php file. Make sure you have a home.blade.php or home.php file in app/views (same applies for travel.blade.php or travel.php).

Unless we can see a stack trace that's the best we can give you for now. Definitely turn on debugging for a dev environment.

Comment: In fact you may want to set your environment to development or local and create an environment folder. For example, once you've set your env to development, you could create app/config/development, and have custom config files in there that only apply so long as your env is set to development (these files would be identical except in setting values to the ones in app/config).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mephoros. As I said, I am completely novice and still learning Laravel. How can I turn on debugging and set local environment? I am developing on my windows under Xampp server. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @Memphoros thanks a million. with the help of debugging, I sorted out my error. there were minor tid bits, and I got my controller working. Cheers with Laravel :)

Comment: No problem. Check out [this series](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch) by Jeffrey Way of Laracasts (some videos free, some require membership @ $9/mo) if you want any more basics of Laravel tips. There's also the Digging In series which can be really helpful.

As for setting your local environment, just go to bootstrap/start.php and look for $env in there.

Answer (score 0):

Use server log, it'll tell you the exact error when you have 500 like this "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.". Most likely you have one component which is not configured right or missing class, missing model, or anything which Laravel can not capture in application level.